# NPN transistor with no resistance at collector?

Tags: operational-amplifier, transistors, analog, npn, transmitter

I'm trying to work my way through a pretty simple laser-based communication system (full description [here](https://www.allaboutcircuits.com/projects/build-a-laser-communication-system/)) project I found online, just as a learning experience.

I'm having issues understanding the the transmitter design (diagrammed below.)

When I simulate it, I get errors. Vcc should be 9V I believe, and Vin is a sinusoidal audio input with Vpp = 2.

[image]

Specifically, this is what confuses me:

1. What's the point of the capacitor between Vcc and ground?
2. How does an NPN transistor work if there's no resistance at the collector? Don't our NPN formulas/relations break down in that case?

Comment: `When I simulate it, I get errors.` ... are we supposed to guess what errors you get? ... please update your post

Comment: You don't need a resistor at the collector. The transistor is in emitter follower mode, so it will produce a voltage at the emitter which is VBase minus (about 0.7V). The Base current is the Emitter current divided by the transistor's gain (hfe) and the collector current is the Emitter current minus the Base current.

Your input sine wave probably needs biasing to half Vcc since the +ve input of the Op Amp is.

Comment: @jsotola I askeded two specific question (numbered 1 and 2), neither of which is related to the simulation.

Comment: @jwb1025 then you should remove the information in your question that causes "noise" and distraction. If both questions are unrelated to something you mention, then it's likely that you are doing yourself a disservice by having that spurious information.

Comment: @jwb1025 I'd be modulating the current. Simple modifications to achieve that. I don't like what I see there. But that doesn't mean you can't get something useful from it. Just it's not how I'd go. A notch filter (perhaps crystal controlled for very high Q) to eliminate any power supply frequencies might be worth a thought. ('Hum' can be annoying.)

Answer (score 7):

> What's the point of the capacitor between Vcc and ground?

It is a decoupling capacitor. It provides short term stabilization of the voltage across the op-amp. The current drawn by the op-amp will change during operation, and at high speed. The capacitor acts as a reservoir, allowing short term current to be drawn quickly when needed, or to hold charge when the op-amp stops drawing current, but current still wants to flow (due to inductance in traces). Without this decoupling capacitor (reservoir) the supply voltage for the op-amp may bounce around, and even the ground plane near the op-amp may bounce around some. Such voltage bounces can cause problems.

> How does an NPN transistor work if there's no resistance at the collector? Don't our NPN formulas/relations break down in that case?

This configuration is called a common collector or emitter follower configuration. The voltage at the emitter closely follows that of the base minus about 1 diode drop, (i.e. somewhere about 0.65 V). The emitter follower does not provide voltage amplification, but it provides low output impedance, suitable for driving heavy loads. That is, it works as a buffer. Although the emitter-follower doesn't have any voltage amplification, the op-amp has limited drive capability, so the emitter-follower provides the needed current.

Comment: Gotcha. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The very muffled sound is caused by the slow photoresistor in the receiver.

The author is wrong because the transmitter opamp output is +3.85V, not +4.5V.
also, the laser diode is probably 1.5V and not the 4.5V the author says.

Here are the quiescent voltages:
[image: laser]